# Hive - How Hive executes multiple BIG tables join query (in MapReduce) internally and how to optimise it?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

Assume I have 4-5 ALL BIG tables (data in TBs) and I want to join them in hive. How optimally will the joins be performed internally (in MapReduce) by Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Many big tables can be joined optimally using Bucketized-Join or Sort-Merge-Join, see [HIVE Join strategies](http://bigdatahandling.blogspot.com/2016/05/sql-join-strategies.html). All tables need to be structured accordingly (bucketed the same, or sorted and bucketed the same way).
If your tables are not organized the same way (bucketed the same) then the only option left is to to a shuffle join, which will copy the entire tables (slow).